# GLUT. Прикрепить к проекту

Tags: glut, c++, opengl

Здравствуйте. Есть проект на Visual C++. Как можно прикрепить библиотеки glut к проекту, что бы при компиляции и запуске этого проекта на другом компьютере не требовалось проводить какие-либо манипуляции с этими библиотеками

Answer (score 1, accepted):

в windows

```
#pragma comment(lib, "Glaux.lib")
```

Comment: у меня две библиотеки: glut32.dll и glut32.lib. Куда девать dll?

Comment: dll клади в c:\windows\system32
lib либо в каталог проэкта либо в каталог библиотек компилятора

Comment: закинул, но на другом компьютере просит glut32.dll, а мне нужно, что бы без проблем всё запускалось

Comment: тогда кидай в каталог с твоим .exe файлом

Comment: спасибо, помогло